# After upgrading ubuntu 12.04 to 18.04 my svn repo is not detected by apache,any help would be appreciated

Tags: server, 18.04, upgrade, apache2, svn

After upgrading ubuntu 12.04 to 18.04 my svn repo is not detecting by apache2, any help would be appreciated.

PFA screenshots---> only revision number is showing not showing the projects[ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BFWa.png)

Comment: You mean that you are trying to view the repo via http? Can you please add more detail about the git setup that you are using.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
<Location />
    DAV svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "svn.mindteck.com"
    AuthUserFile /var/local/svn/svn.mindteck.com/conf/passwd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/svn/svn.mindteck.com/authz
    SVNPath /var/local/svn/svn.mindteck.com
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

Comment: This is my /etc/apache2/sites-availavle/000-default.conf

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include those details? You'll get better responses that way too, as the comments don't show in the summarised question listing. And you can put the conf file in a pastebin and include the link.